# Kusto query Past 3 days data with setting 0 for no data for that date

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

First time trying kql, hope someone could help me.
I need past 3 days of each day event count with respect to created date and by each of the user.

Result would be something like:

| Created | User | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 31/05/2023 | Ali | 1 |
| 30/05/2023 | Ali | 0 |
| 29/05/2023 | Ali | 2 |
| 31/05/2023 | Ken | 1 |
| 30/05/2023 | Ken | 2 |
| 29/05/2023 | Ken | 0 |

If there is no data on that day, put 0 as the count. I tried something like:

```
events
| where created >= ago(3d)  
| summarize Count = count() by created = bin(created, 1d), user
| project created = format_datetime(created, 'dd/MM/yyyy'), user, Count
| order by created desc
```

But how can i fill the 0 for the count for the day that has no data?

Answer (score 2):

You can consider using the [`make-series` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/make-seriesoperator) instead of the `summarize` operator